# route reader reading record multiple times in parallel processing

Tags: multithreading, parallel-processing, routes, apache-camel, synchronization

I have apache camel route as below:-

```
get("fileReaderSvc", fileReaderSvc")
.rocess(e->fileReaderSvc.init(e, ctx)
.split(body().convertToString.tokenize("/n"))
.streming()
.parallelProcessing(true)
.thread(10)
.to("direct:nextRoute")
.end();

get("nextRoute", "nextRoute")
.choice()
.when(body().startWith("HDR"))
.bean("process","processHdr")
.when(body().startsWith("REC"))
.bean("process","processRecord")
.end()
```

My problem is I have a file that has over 1000 records where only one starts with "HDR".  But processHdr is getting called multiple times. Looks synchronization issue. Looks to me multiple threads reading same record. This code showing the issue on Linux mostly.
Please suggest.

Here fileReaderSvc extends from FileReaderService and init and readFile calls super.methods.

Answer (score 0):

Issue was not this code. File move failed triggering multiple reading.